# Updation of API url and port in reactjs build dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs - Updation in Reactjs build dynamically. Iam fetching data from api for whole application. API: http://cpcppcdsgd0 and port:9090. Client wants to update with his apis hostname and port in ReactJs build. Can client update it?

Comment: as long as you can put that information on a different fixed server

Comment: Entirely depends on your code. Did you save API url in a .env file? Are you reading it from a constant file in your code? It can be as easy as having an input for user to type the desired API url. So please show us your code and we can help you.

Comment: I tried both options: one is .env file and also from constant file. Where i have to create input to change it in build folder? Can client update in reactjs build bundle chunk file? How can he update in chunk compressed file dynamically?

Comment: How can we create input for user to type the desired API url and update in reactjs build?